# I am getting an error while trying to create a database in Phpmyadmin. (No Privileges)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I tried to change my administrator password. But I was not successful. When I try this, I get this error :

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

The operating system I use : 
Linux version 4.18.0-parrot10-amd64 (team@parrotsec.org) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Debian 7.3.0-29)) #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-1parrot10 (2018-10-06)

Comment: Let's see how you tried to access mysql.  It says `NO`, meaning you tried to get in without specifying a password.  This is usually dues to a syntax error during accessing.

Comment: Thanks bro. I solved the problem. I was having trouble because Mysql continued to work in the background. I've killed all processes. Then I created a new administrator password.

Comment: See also `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`.